# How to connect 3 dropdown list to live search in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, search

I am trying to take my live search code in PHP and 3 drop down box have the values from db so my users can select what category they want to search for instead of displaying in DataTable below. They(3 drop down boxes) are only work independent. How do I link them together.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHec0.png)

It is my code to get value from dropdown boxes on the UI.

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function()
{
if (true) {
    $("#fetchal").on('change',function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    $.ajax(
    {
        url:'search.php',
        type:'POST',
        data:'request1='+value,
        beforeSend:function()
        {
            $("#table-container").html("Working on...");
        },
        success:function(data)
        {
            $("#table-container").html(data);
        },
    });
});
}
if (true){
    $("#search_MONTH").on('change',function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    $.ajax(
    {
        url:'search.php',
        type:'POST',
        data:'request2='+value,
        beforeSend:function()
        {
            $("#table-container").html("Working on...");
        },
        success:function(data)
        {
            $("#table-container").html(data);
        },
    });
});
}
if (true){
    $("#search_YEAR").on('change',function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    $.ajax(
    {
        url:'search.php',
        type:'POST',
        data:'request3='+value,
        beforeSend:function()
        {
            $("#table-container").html("Working on...");
        },
        success:function(data)
        {
            $("#table-container").html(data);
        },
    });
});
}
});
```

and
It is my code on search.php below

```
if (isset($_POST['request1'],$_POST['request2'],$_POST['request3'])) {
$request1 = $_POST['request1'];
$request2 = $_POST['request2'];
$request3 = $_POST['request3'];
require_once("includes/connection.php");
//CAU LENH SQL
$sql5= "SELECT * from form where center ='$request1' and  month(createdate) = '$request2' and  year(createdate) = '$request3' order by id ";
$result5 = $conn->query($sql5);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am not sure to understand but let me try,

You may check on an element change if others two are filled or not:

exemple:

```
$("#fetchal").on('change',function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    $("#search_MONTH").val()
    $("#search_YEAR").val()
    if(empty... or ... != ""...)
{
```

i let you end this code,

to escape repetition though your code you could do an array with all three ID's and just doing a foreach of your tab,
exemple of tab :

```
    var fields = [
        {variable: search_MONTH, id:"search_MONTH" },
        {variable: search_YEAR, id:"search_YEAR" },
        {variable: fetchal, id:"fetchal" }
    ]
```